# How can I add a function(Underline) on ckeditor4-react config?

Tags: reactjs, ckeditor4-react

React Version: 18.1.0

`Ckeditor4-react` *tag*:

```
<CKEditor
    onChange={(even) => {
        onChangeCk(even, 'description');
    }}
    data={formData.description}
    config={ckeditorUploadConfig}
    
/>
```

`ckeditorUploadConfig`:

```
export const ckeditorUploadConfig = {
  filebrowserImageUploadUrl: `${getApiBaseUrl('REACT_APP_API_MASTER_DATA')}/api/ckeditor/upload`,
  fileTools_requestHeaders: {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${authService.getAccessTokenFromStorage()}`,
  },
};
```

I even try to add in *extraPlugins* or *toolbar* directly but it don't event work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using ckeditor4-react,I use ckeditor 4 react advanced for more function and compatible with react.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ckeditor4-react-advanced